# Como fazer um update em uma coluna no banco de dados auto incremente e levando em conta um ordenamento

Tags: sql, sql-server

Preciso fazer um update em uma tabela do banco alterando uma coluna com o valor auto incremente porem devo levar em conta um ordenamento, eu consegui pelo seguinte codigo fazer o update com auto incremente mas não conseguir fazer levando em conta o ordenamento, o campo do ordenamento esta na mesma tabela do update com o nome Descricao.

```
  DECLARE @count int
  SET @count = 0
  update MinhaTabela set Codigo = @count, @count=@count+1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma vez que não pode usar a cláusula ORDER BY num update, pode por exemplo, realizar o update indirectamente através de uma CTE.

```
;WITH CTE As
(
  SELECT Codigo, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Descricao) AS RN
    FROM MinhaTabela
)
UPDATE CTE
   SET Codigo = RN
```

Se quiser que o Codigo inicie no 0 (Zero), basta substituir 1 ao RN:

```
;WITH CTE As
(
  SELECT Codigo, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Descricao) AS RN
    FROM MinhaTabela
)
UPDATE CTE
   SET Codigo = RN - 1
```

Comment: Muito bom deu certo eu não conhecia CTE tenho pouco conhecimento com MSSQL, vou dar um estudada em cima para eu entender melhor. OBG